# Trouble reading from a file and writing to a file in Java

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have an issue when trying to read data from a file in Java and then write it to a csv file. I set up an ArrayList variable 'data', use a Scanner to read the lines from the data file. The issue comes when the data is read and I print it on this line: System.out.println(line);

It comes out like this:

```
[Tim]
[Tim]
[March]
[Tim]
[March]
[11751 N River Dr]
[Tim]
[March]
[11751 N River Dr]
[Apt 4]
[Tim]
[March]
[11751 N River Dr]
[Apt 4]
[Mankato]
[Tim]
[March]
[11751 N River Dr]
[Apt 4]
[Mankato]
[MN]
[Tim]
[March]
[11751 N River Dr]
[Apt 4]
[Mankato]
[MN]
[56001]
```

When the file just looks like this:

```
[Tim]
[March]
[11751 N River Dr]
[Apt 4]
[Mankato]
[MN]
[56001]
```

Is there a reason that it is printing the lines somewhat erratically? Do I need to include a loop somewhere to just print the main lines once? My second issue is when I try to write the file as a CSV one I am having an issue where it is just printing the last line (56001) and not any of the other lines. Is there a thing that I am missing to do this? This is the code that I have so far.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ReadFromDat {

/**
 * @param <Data>
 * @param args
 */
  public static ArrayList<String> data;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Tim\\Desktop\\data.dat"));
    data= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> line = null;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()){
        data.add(sc.nextLine());
        for (String lines: data) {
            line = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(lines.split("\n")));
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        //line = Arrays.asList(data.split("\n"));
        //System.out.println(data);
        FileWriter output = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Tim\\Desktop\\data.csv");
        for (String data: line) {
            output.write(data);
        }
        output.close();

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: [Learn how to debug.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

You are reopening your output file in every iteration of your loop. FileWriter by default overwrites, that's why you get only one line in your output file.

You need to move the FileWriter out of the loop.